# Python. Поддерживает ли Series будучи топом данных int пустые значения?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Есть большой датасет и есть столбец у которого тип данных `float64` и в нём куча пустых значений.
Возможно ли присвоить ему тип данных `int`, но пустые значения оставить пустыми? (нулями заполнять не хочу, чтобы нули не влияли не среднее).

Answer (score 3):

Более-менее свежие версии `Pandas` поддерживают такую возможность с помощью специального целого типа [Int64Dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, None, pd.NA], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
print(s)
```

Вывод:

```
0       1
1       2
2    <NA>
3    <NA>
4    <NA>
dtype: Int64
```